# Simple grep regex to catch [0 0] but not [00]

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

Buongiorno,

I am trying to grep all the patterns that look like: [00 0] or [ 0000] but not [00] or [0000] : there has to be at least one space.

Naively, I thought that

```
grep -P '\[.* .*\]'
```

would do it ; when I copy paste the regex in regex101 with some test cases, I get the following:

```
unmatched:
0 0
000
[00]
[0]
[00]

matched:
[0 0]
[ 0]
[0 ]
[  0  ]
[ 0 ]
```

which is exactly what I want.

But grep seems to match also the things between brackets but with no space:

```
[00]
[0]
[00]
```

What am I missing ?

```
\[0* 0*\]
```

seems to work but I'm going to have cases where it's not only 0...

Comment: Is `0` meant to be any number, or are they literal zeroes?

Comment: Does there have to be at least a character other than space too? What about a space that is the delimiter of the two characters being spaces too. Does that count?

Comment: checking from my command's output it's actually an O, but I'd like to be safe and resilient to whatever characters there may be - . or o are things that wouldn't surprise me for instance. Basically what I want to know is : is there at least a space in the pair of brackets. There is at least one character between the brackets, which can be a space or a filler character.

Comment: Whether it's `O`s or `0`s or any other character other than `]` in the input would make no different to your `grep` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `grep` would work with BRE (basic regex), it doesn't require ERE (extended regex) or *experimental* `-P` (perl regex):

```bash
grep '\[[^] ]* [^]]*]' file

[0 0]
[ 0]
[0 ]
[  0  ]
[ 0 ]
```

If you have only zeroes and spaces inside the `[...]` then try:

```
grep '\[0* [0 ]*]' file
```

[**Online Demo**](https://ideone.com/mo7op2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\[`: Match a `[`
- `[^] ]*`: Match 0 or more of any chars that are not `]` and space
- : Match a space
- `[^]]*`: Match 0 or more of any chars that are not `]`
- `]`: Match a `]`

**Problem** with `.*` is that it matches 0 or more of any character except a line break. It won't stop at `]`.

Comment: > This grep would work with BRE, it doesn't even ERE (extended regex):

why ? man grep tells me that -P enables perl-compatible regexes (and -E enables ERE, it's the latest GNU grep)

Comment: I didn't use *experimental* `-P` or `-E` because we don't really need them. This problem can be solved using default BRE

Comment: yes, but I don't understand the " It won't stop at ]." ; grep's colored output with my regex highlights e.g. [00] but not what's after in for instance "[00] foo bar"

Comment: no, I already have coloured output, what I mean is that it matches only up to ] with my regex: https://imgur.com/a/NUJv7iK

Comment: ok got it.. your regex will also match `'[0] [1]'` which should not be matched

Answer (score 1):

The OPs regexp would not match the strings they thought it did regardless of whether `-P` or `-E` or no flag was used. Instead the command `vmtouch -v` in the image the OP posted at https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSrDg.jpg and mentioned in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73266447/simple-grep-regex-to-catch-0-0-but-not-00#comment129395293_73266479) contains unexpected characters which showed up when the OP was directed to pipe the `vmtouch -v` output to `od -c` to make them visible.

Comment: doesn't seem to change anything: https://i.imgur.com/UhsWetJ.png

Comment: here is the complete output of vmtouch in that case for reference: https://i.imgur.com/5bnBWff.png

Comment: ah, but there is something weird though - if I echo this text into grep directly by copy-pasting it in the terminal then it properly does not match

Comment: pipe the vmtouch output to `od -c` instead of `grep` to see if any odd characters show up. Whatever the problem is, it's not your regexp.

Comment: ah exactly, this was that. actual "output" is "/usr/bin/true..[OOOOOOO] 7/7.[OOOOOOO] 7/7..    ". thus ending in the case mentioned by @anubhava. I wonder what I can do to protect myself against this in the future ?

Comment: I suspect there's also `CR`s in that mix. Edit your question to show the output formatted as a code block so we can help you further.

Comment: See if the issues with the output show up by just piping to `cat -v` or `cat -Ev` and, if so, add that output to your question.